# Get value from json response with SOAP request

Tags: php, soap

After successfully getting a response from a SOAP request in JSON format, I cannot extract one property out of it.

Beholde the response I got from postman.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
    <AutenticacionResponse xmlns="https://figs.software/">
    <AutenticacionResult xsi:type="xsd:string">{"CodRespuesta":"00","Respuesta":"bd026f95-61cf-4947-80df-bf519d544995","URL":null,"NCF":null}</AutenticacionResult>
    </AutenticacionResponse>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

My goad is to get the token of the **Respuesta** property.

I'm using curl of PHP to establish the connection:
I try to convert the response I got into an array like this:

```
     $response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
    $body = $xml->xpath('//soapBody ')[0];
    $array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$body), TRUE); 
    echo  $array['AutenticacionResponse']['AutenticacionResult'];
    echo gettype($array);
```

I have this result:

```
 {"CodRespuesta":"00","Respuesta":"d5810796-9563-4423-aff3-089d61e170b6","URL":null,"NCF":null}
   array
```

How can I get the value of **Respuesta** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without touching your code I get the answer by just doing

```
$json = json_decode($array['AutenticacionResponse']['AutenticacionResult'], true);
echo $json['Respuesta'];
```

And I would have done like this

```
<?php
$response = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<AutenticacionResponse xmlns="https://figs.software/">
<AutenticacionResult xsi:type="xsd:string">{"CodRespuesta":"00","Respuesta":"bd026f95-61cf-4947-80df-bf519d544995","URL":null,"NCF":null}</AutenticacionResult>
</AutenticacionResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML;

$response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
$json = json_decode($xml->soapBody->AutenticacionResponse->AutenticacionResult, true);
echo $json['Respuesta'];
```

Comment: Good job bro, you have made my day for programming.

Comment: Welcome...if so, don't forget to vote "this answer is useful" please (arrow up at the left)

Comment: I did it right away because I know the rule ):